# Convert wordpress site to HTTPS

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl

I've googled this extensively, but I'm having problems with this.

I have a free Let's Encrypt SSL certificate from my cloudways.com shared platform.

I want to change my wordpress site to be exclusively HTTPS.

I have tried following guides such as: https://css-tricks.com/moving-to-https-on-wordpress/ but to no avail.

So far I have tried:

1. Manually editing the htaccess file
2. changing the site address in the wordpress dashboard > settings screen

I get a mixture of errors depending what I try:

- A "redirecting too many times" browser / server timeout message
- A mess: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sG96r.jpg (is this mixed content, perhaps?)

I'm thinking that my .htaccess file is too messy, everything I've tried on this file so far makes things messy: https://codedump.io/share/YsiXzoMZ3b8l/1/htaccess

I'm all out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your in a loop of redirects via your .htaccess file.

http://www.redirect-checker.org/
You could check this site for that.

Comment: Thanks! I checked it, came back fine.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me: https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/

Really simple ssl